# How to set app background via the SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, image, sharedpreferences

I want to allow users to change my app's background from the settings (for the Main_UI activity class). I am not able to store the uri in a string since there is no startActivityForResult() method that could extract the intent's uri (The Preferences only allow starting an intent, preferably to other settings)(I tried creating custom Preference Class but again, not startActivityForResult). I tried doing it via the menu options, taking the uri and creating a drawable from it. But when I apply that drawable to my RelativeLayout instance, it says its supported only beyond API 16. Mine is 15.
Any help would be really appreciated, since this android is getting on my nerves.

Comment: Question 1: can't you update your API?
Suggestion: Create a SharedPreference (Type String, int, however you like) and then a method that is run on startup of your application that sets the background depending on whether that preference is set, and how it is set.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but thats not what I want. I want to change the background from the settings itself. I don't think API update is necessary since APIs before 15 also offered background change.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach to support lower version API(s):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
    yourLayout.setBackground(yourDrawable);
else
    yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(yourDrawable);
```

---

**Using SharedPreferences**

In the settings activity:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();

edit.putString("bg_drawable_uri", bgDrawableUri);
edit.commit();
```

And in main activity:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
settings.getString("bg_drawable_uri", "default_uri");
```

Comment: yes I know how to save and get uri as strings from the preferences, what I want is to be able to **choose to change the wallpaper from the settings itself** and the result be saved in the preferences, like in whatsapp etc apps. Though the Build.Version trick is really helpful :)

Comment: I can't get your mean. Why you want to do it with `startActivityForResult` instead of reading image uri from setting in the main activity?

Comment: I don't want to do it with startActivityForResult, I just want to be able to choose the wallpaper from the settings. I want an Option in settings that takes me to the image chooser gallery and saves the result. Other option could be to create a Setting activity but that would be against the "best practices"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old and probably there might be better ways today, but what worked for me was to just create an ImageView, set the uri and then retrieve the drawable from the ImageView, like so:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImageURI(someUri);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(imageView.getDrawable());
```